# Why can a single parameterized type in static method take two different types?

Tags: java, generics

```
class MyGeneric <T> {
    void method(T t1, T t2){}
}

class App{
    static <T> void smethod(T t1, T t2){}
    //Java will infer the most specific supertype of the arguments passed in

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyGeneric<String> mg = new MyGeneric<>();
        //! mg.method("hello", 123);// understandable

        smethod("hello", 123);// not understandable
    }
}
```

Why are they different?

Comment: "hello" (String) and 123 (Integer) share a single common ancestor (Object). Notice you specify the type in `MyGeneric`, but don't in `App`. The equivalent code would be `App.<String>smethod("abc", 123);` (which will give you a compiler error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this.

So basically in the Java code you provided, the behavior of the `method` in the `MyGeneric` class and the `smethod` static method in the `App` class is different due to the context and the way Java's type inference works in different situations.

In more detail:

In the `MyGeneric` class, you've defined a generic method `method` that takes two parameters of type `T`. The type parameter `T` for this method is determined by the type parameter of the `MyGeneric` class itself. When you instantiate `MyGeneric<String>`, the type parameter `T` becomes `String`, so the `method` expects two arguments of type `String`.

The `smethod` is a static generic method defined in the `App` class. When you invoke `smethod("hello", 123)`, Java uses type inference to determine the most specific supertype that is applicable to both `"hello"` (a `String`) and `123` (an `Integer`). In this case, the most specific supertype that both `String` and `Integer` have in common is `Object`. Therefore, the type parameter `T` for `smethod` is inferred to be `Object`, and the method is effectively treated as if it's defined as `static void smethod(Object t1, Object t2)`.

This difference in behavior arises from the context in which the generic method is defined and the type inference mechanism used by Java. In the case of the `MyGeneric` class, the type parameter `T` is determined by the instantiation of the class, and the `method` is bound to a specific type. In the case of the `smethod` in the `App` class, the type parameter `T` is inferred based on the actual arguments provided to the method, and the type inference tries to find a common supertype.

Basically the behavior of the two methods is different because of the context in which they are defined and the way Java's type inference works.

Comment: Excuse me, is it your answer or chatGpt?

Answer (score 1):

> take two different types?

No, they don't take two different types at all.

They take one type. And that type, here, is `java.lang.Object`.

### The meta-aspect of generics

Generics isn't about the types of specific things. It's about the types of the method, itself. It's about *your code*, not about what the runtime type of things are. It helps to keep in mind that generics are **entirely** a thing `javac` does. `java.exe` has few generics to work with (most of it is erased), and **has no idea what they are** - you can read through the entire JVM Specification and it simply doesn't even recognize they exist. Other than describe how they are stored in .class files. They are like comments: Completely ignored at runtime. Hence, the only thing generics can ever do, is modify what the compiler does with your code. Thus: Generics operate on 'lines of code' level.

To make that more concrete:

`List<? extends Number>` does not mean: "A list that can store anything that is a Number or a subclass thereof". No, it means: "This list stores.. I don't actually know what it stores (hence, the question mark). All I know is, there is *some sort* of restriction, and I also know that this restriction is either `Number`, *or* some subtype of it. Hence, `.add()` doesn't work at all (there is nothing you can add to this list), but `.get()` gets you, at least, Number. That's for sure.

Note that: "A list that can store anything that is a Number or a subclass thereof" is perfectly described by `List<Number>`. Not `List<? extends Number>`. After all, all `Integer` instances are also `Number`. If `(x instanceof Integer)` resolves to true, `(x instanceof Number)` is guaranteed to also do so. Hence, `List<Number> list = ...; list.add(5);` is legal already.

The same happens in a signature:

> ```java
> static <T> void smethod(T t1, T t2){}
> ```

Means: *Callers* will, for every line of code in the project that calls this method, have **the compiler** figure out a `T` that works, and acts as if this method has all its 'T' replaced with that type. Given that this is just a thing the compiler does, and the `smethod` method is likely already compiled, that has no effect whatsoever on how this method runs, but it does affect how the line of code that calls it 'acts' - it acts as if that method was `smethod(WhateverTypeTheCompilerChose t1, ExactSameTypeHere t2)`.

### Inference

If you don't explicitly pick what that type should be, e.g. with `TypeThatIsIn.<String>smethod(a, b)`, then the compiler will **infer** - it will try to figure out what you meant.

It does that by checking for the most specific commonality between every place you use 'T' at the call-site. In this case, you pass an expression of type String and one of type Integer (auto-boxed from `int`, because generics can't be primitive). The most specific common super type between those two isn't 'non-existent'.. it does exist.

It's `java.lang.Object`.

So the compiler dutifully acts as if the signature really reads `static void smethod(Object a, Object b)`.

Calling `smethod("hello", 123)` would be a perfectly valid call.